# How to find out if a Unicode code point is a "normal" printable one in Java?

Tags: java, unicode

I have to explain what I mean with "normal":

- the character has (or should have) a (not completely white) glyph unless it is in the Space Separator category (Character.getType(codepoint)==Character.SPACE_SEPARATOR) and
- if using a monospaced font it should occupy one position and advance the cursor one position to the right under all circumstances.

Counter-examples:

- U+000A LINE FEED (not one position to the right)
- U+0300 COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT (not one position to the right)
- U+05D0 HEBREW LETTER ALEF (right to left)
- U+2060 WORD JOINER (not one position to the right)
- U+E000 PRIVATE USE (no character assigned)

The predicate must detect code points that are not "normal" reliably. It does not need to support all code points, but only that "in common use in one of the EU languages".

The latter criterium is somehow difficult, too - so the best solution would be to cover the complete unicode range (or only exclude ranges that are clearly not european or ancient).

Is it possible to base the predicate only on the Unicode character category?

Comment: Maybe you have a look over general unicode categories in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html and white list oder black list some categories until you have your expected behavior.

Comment: It's not enough to look over the categories in that class, it is necessary to look at the Unicode standard text itself. The standard is huge and I would appreciate some hints from an Unicode expert here. Before going to the categories, it would make sense to answer the above question if the category alone is enough.

Comment: "until you have the expected behaviour": this is not a trivial task. How would you do that?

Comment: Why do you assume that “it is necessary to look at the Unicode standard text itself”? The categories reported by `java.lang.Character` *are* from the Unicode standard. Java code doesn’t check whether its author has read the text of the standard personally, so you should be clearer about why the categories reported by `java.lang.Character` are not sufficient. Perhaps the main problem stems from the fact that you can’t determine whether a particular monospaced font will support a character, by just looking at the `char`s…

Comment: @Holger: For example:  Take the criterium "not completely white glyph". Which categories guarantee that the glyphs of all their characters are all white (does the Space Separator category do that?), which categories guarantee that none of their characters are completely white and which categories provide no such guarantee?

Comment: @Gustave: Look at the last sentence of my previous comment: *you can’t determine whether a particular monospaced font will support a character, by just looking at the chars*. A font may not support a particular white-space character, causing a non-white fall-back glyph to be rendered. It might be strange, but the font could have an all-white glyph as fallback either. And that’s within the specification. Beyond that, there is no guaranty how a font will map characters to glyphs at all. It might have visible glyphs for white-space characters or render non-space characters all-white.

Comment: Let me put it more precise: I am not interested in actual font implementations, but in what a font should normally do. It is completely obvious that the glyph of the letter 'A' of the english alphabet is a normal character according to my definition of "normal", even if some font may not support that for whatever reason.

Comment: "Lateinische Zeichen in Unicode" (https://www.xoev.de/die_standards/lateinische_zeichen_in_unicode-4813) defines a reasonable subset of Unicode for European languages for which it is practically possible to answer the question.